# CheckedListBox SetItemCheckState

Tags: c#, listbox, states

i have:

```
ListenCheckedListBox.SetItemCheckState(0, CheckState.Unchecked);
```

will this assignment trigger the ListBox's ItemCheck event?

because the above statement is not changing its status from checked to unchecked. and in the ItemCheck im toggling its CheckState also. that why im wondering that because of this code the checked status stays unchanged.

thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method should fire the OnItemCheck event yes, if the check state changed.  It fires before the item actually gets its checked state set.